# Burn the [home] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Yes, there is a tag named [home](/questions/tagged/home). It doesn't even have a tag wiki and has *347 questions* currently tagged to it. Most of the questions can be easily moved to other tags as they are related to

- Java home [java-home](/questions/tagged/java-home)
- Home page [homepage](/questions/tagged/homepage)
- Home screen [homescreen](/questions/tagged/homescreen)

And the other questions are totally unrelated. They simply have this tag in this question. So could we burninate it, as it really does not make sense to have a tag, just named [home](/questions/tagged/home).

Comment: *There's no place like [home]... there's no place like [home]...*

Comment: You probably want a [meta-tag:retag-request] rather than a [meta-tag:burninate-request]; after all uses are edited out, the tag will automatically go away, and I'd hope that anyone with the power to recreate it would have the sense not to.

Comment: Even if all the questions are *re-tagged*, the tag will remain(atleast till 24 hrs I guess), and someone else might use it. So why not, re-tag and burn it probably?!

Comment: phh, just keep an eye on it. 347 questions don't indicate that there will be a new question every minute (unlike [tag:homework])

Comment: burning down the house?